# Validate if i enter Alphabet

Tags: javascript, html

I make a simple program that when i enter any number in text box it add 3 in it.
I want to validate if user enter text then it shows a message "YOU ENTER TEXT".
if i enter any text my if-else is not working
here is my code
HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<input type="button" value="EXECUTE" onClick="add()">
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

JS:

```
function add(){
    var num1=document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    var a=parseInt(num1);

    if(typeof a==='String'){
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML="THIS IS STRING";    
        }
    else{

    var ans=(a+3);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=ans;
    }
    }
```

Comment: `parseInt()` won't ever return a string (and it will ignore non-numeric characters after any leading digits). The `typeof` operator won't ever return `'String'` with a capital `S`. If you want to test for non-digits in your input string a regex test is the simplest method.

Comment: @nnnnnn Dude problem is thaat if i don't use parseint js is just concatenate it

Comment: @Naga Sai A is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result use isNaN() instead of typeof

```
function add() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  var a = parseInt(num1);

  if (isNaN(a)) {
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "THIS IS STRING";
  } else {

    var ans = (a + 3);
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = ans;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NAyAWL

Comment: YOU ARE LIFE SAVIOUR

Comment: What if the user types "123abc"? Shouldn't that be considered invalid?